# How is data replicated in a apache cassandra 3.11 cluster with RF=3 and 5 racks

Tags: cassandra

Suppose I have a cassandra cluster on 3 racks, lets say on 3 AZs in AWS and have a keyspace with RF=3. With this configuration, One replica will be present in each AZ.

1. What happens to the data when I add 2 more nodes to this cluster on 2new racks, AZ4 and AZ5? How do the replicas get resdistributed?
2. What happens to new data being added to this 5 rack cluster? How are replicas maintained?

When I tried it on AWS EC2, I see equal percentage allocation on all racks on running ./nodetool status

Answer (score 1):

When the racks are equal to the RF as you currently have - 3 and 3, Cassandra walks the racks with the replicas and puts a replica in each rack it finds so it works out nicely and each rack gets a full copy of the data.

When you add two additional racks, the replicas will walk the racks and try to divide up the ownership so it is somewhat equal as you mentioned.  In this scenario, no rack would contain a full replica, but ownership will be split among the racks.

If you intend to divide racks into AZs, then to get the most benefit, it's best to maintain the RF of 3 with 3 racks as you have it.  If additional nodes are needed to scale up the current cluster, then add three nodes, one to each rack to keep them balanced.  If you want additional copies of the data stored in separate AZs, add a second DC and maintain a rack/RF ratio that stores full replicas in the additional racks.

Comment: What would happen if I try to go from this 5 rack setup to 3 rack setup? Will cassandra redistribute such that each AZ is back to holding 1 replica each?

Comment: Correct, Cassandra will place replicas based on the number of racks, so if you move back to 3 racks with a replication factor of 3, then each rack would get a replica unless you were defining tokens manually when bootstrapping.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Paul
In case I want to go to a 3rack setup, what's the best way to achieve it?
Options as I see it are either using the replace_address_first_boot to replace instance in any of the first 3 racks, or decommission the nodes in rack4/5.
I know a full repair would be needed at the end, but till the repair is done, will I see data inconsistency because of token reallocation?

Comment: I agree you could either replace the nodes, or you could decommission the existing nodes, wipe the data, then bootstrap them to the appropriate rack, either way should work fine.